# Does iptables options order matters in a rule?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, firewall

Is there a difference when the `options` order is changed between this 3 rules?

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 9000 -m set --match-set someSet src -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m set --match-set someSet src --dport 9000 -p tcp --syn -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT --dport 9000 -p tcp --syn -m set --match-set someSet src -j ACCEPT
```

Does the traversal follow the option order in the rules?

Take this rule for example:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 9000 -m set --match-set someSet src -j ACCEPT
```

Does it mean iptables look first for `SYN` then check if destination port equal 9000 and last look for a match in the set?

And on this example:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m set --match-set someSet src --dport 9000 -p tcp --syn -j ACCEPT
```

Does it mean iptables look first for a match in the set then check if destination port equal 9000 and last look up for `SYN`?

although they all give the same result when being accepted but they might be more optimised when being rejected if order is taking place in iptables `options`.

Answer (score 0):

Order of options is for most part not relevant.

You could verify this by saving the rules , you should see that they all end up the same way.

Logical order would be:
Protocol, port, state, module

Comment: What if the set contains millions of ip's.. you can't expect the performance to be the same if the the traversal would start from the set matching and fall on the others

Comment: Set is a module, expect it to be checked last. If you want to optimise it yourself use separate rules sending traffic to new chains which in turn does the next part of the match. But be warned that might not be a optimization at all.

Comment: I know chain would do the trick but I'd rather add as least as possible rules, how can I determine the filter order in one rule?

Comment: @iTaMaR, you're likely seeking to optimize something inconsequential. Again, have you actually benchmarked anything before attempting overly complicated, brain racking optimizations? `ipset` is designed to handle large volumes of IPs and strives to make looking up an IP constant time no matter the number of IPs in the set so the operation should be fairly cheap.

Comment: @Ginnungagap No algorithm for any kind of set can match comparing 16 bits with each other or matching `opcode`, there is no magic no matter how efficient it will be!!! And you know what, its for science reasons not benchmarking, all I asked was how does `iptables` filter `rules` and if order is taking place..